# How can I find an object (or objects) if an array field contains a value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As you see in the title, I want to query items if an item's array-typed field contains specified value with Mongoose.

I found that mongo DB / Mongoose provides '$in' operator to find values with array objects.

But '$in' operator is only useful in opposite case (To find values if a value's field is in the array).

Here are some codes for model that I wrote.

```
// scheme/item.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var model = new mongoose.Schema({

    item_id : Number,

    name : String,
    description : String,

    assigned : [ Number ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('item', model);
```

What I want to do is that if user id is set, find all items where item.assigned contains user's id.

Comment: Have you tried `Item.find({assigned: userId})`?

Comment: @chridam I think you gave me a correct answer .. what a life-saver thx !!

Answer (score 0):

To get all records that have `assigned` which is not null you need to use the [$ne](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/query.html) clause:

```
item.find({assigned: {$ne: null}});
```

Comment: Sorry but I wanted to find records which has an array field that contains a value, but just all records that has not null field.

It means that item's field shouldn't be null and 'contains a value'.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I did not understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
item.find({'$and' : [{item_id : {$eq: req.session.user_id}}, {'assigned ' : {'$in' : [req.session.user_id]}}]})
```

I think you can use `$in`, please read the link:https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

Comment: I edited some data for model and explanation after your comment. Actually, Item.id is not relavant in this problem (so I edited to 'item_id'). In fact, when the user's id comes with some objects (eg. req.session.user_id), I would like to use this value for query. Sorry for mistyping :(

Answer (score 0):

With @chridam 's comment, I found 'Item.find({ assigned : user_id })' just do what I intented.